# Regex match word after negated set

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently trying to match the following cases with Regex.

**Current regex**

`\.\/[^/]\satoms\s\/[^/]+\/index\.js`

**Cases**

```
// Should match
./atoms/someComponent/index.js 
./molecules/someComponent/index.js
./organisms/someComponent/index.js

// Should not match
./atomsdsd/someComponent/index.js
./atosdfms/someComponent/index.js
./atomssss/someComponent/index.js
```

However none of the cases are matching, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @anubhava using this in javascript, testing via https://regex101.com/

Comment: the `\s` tokens in your regex are saying there *must* be whitespace characters in between the slashes in and the text string "atom", which is not what you want, based off your example.

Comment: `someComponent/index.js`, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help you out. You have added some addition characters which lets your regex to fail.

**Regex:** `\.\/(atoms|molecules|organisms)\/[^\/]+\/index\.js`

> **1.** `\.\/` This will match `./`
>
> **2.** `(atoms|molecules|organisms)` This will match either `atoms` or `molecules` or `organisms`
>
> **3.** `\/[^\/]+\/` This will match `/` and then till `/`
>
> **4.** `index\.js` This will match `index.js`

[**Regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pLAztc/3)

Comment: Great! See my updated question, forgot to include 2 more words that I would like to match in the same line (if possible). Thank you so much!

Comment: Will accept as soon as I can, great answer now I finally know how to do this. I'm such a noob in regex --_--

Comment: well explained answer ++

Comment: @NealVDV I recommend briefly reading though all of the different regex operators available, it will help you next time:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

why not just this [simpler pattern](https://regex101.com/r/VyesvV/2/)?

```
\.\/(atoms|molecules|organisms)\/.*?index\.js
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I will ever encounter this but `./atoms/////////someComponent/index.js` still matches, and should not. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
\.\/(atoms|molecules|organisms)\/[a-zA-Z]*\/index\.js
```

Forward slashes (and other special characters) should be escaped with a back slash `\`.

1. `\.\/(atoms|molecules|organisms)\/` matches '.atoms/' or `.molecules` or `organisms` *strictly*. Without the parenthesis it will match partial strings. the `|` is an alternation operator that matches either everything to the left or everything to the right.
2. `[a-zA-Z]*` will match a string of any length with characters in any case. `a-z` accounts for lower case while `A-Z` accounts for upper case. `*` indicates one or more characters. Depending on what characters may be in `someCompenent` you may need to account for numbers using `[a-zA-Z\d]*`.
3. `\/index\.js` will match '/index.js'